# How do I use a second keyboard and mouse - When running a separate X server on the same graphics card

Tags: xserver, multiseat

I have 2x mice, 2x keybard, 2x monitor 1x graphics.

Can I make it a second computer? (for no reason at all)

--OR--

Would it be easier with a second VGA: As I do have a decent extra ATI card (7750 series) HOWEVER... I am currently using Nvidia

Answer (score 1):

You could always get a [KVM switch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KVM_switch). This will let you switch back and forth between mice, keyboard, monitors, with the press of a button, but you would need 2 computers connected to the switch.

Check this one out for [multiseated device](https://superuser.com/questions/12284/dedicated-mouse-and-keyboard-for-a-virtual-machine-is-it-possible), which is what I believe you are trying to do.

Comment: Trying to run 2 systems on the same processor, yes.

Comment: @TardisGuy edited answer

Comment: AAHHHhhhhhhh ohhhhhhhhhh .... ... .. .. 
That will work for something else.
ALMOST exactly what I need.

Comment: But I need to do this with 2 Xservers on linux. But that is Clever. I suppose Ill need to edit devices in xorg.conf away from corepointer/corekeybard etc... I have NO IDEA how to do that.